# How to solve the problem 'Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-lookup.c: 112: check_match' when using library jzy3d?

Tags: java-11, jzy3d

When running any 3d plot using jzy3d with Java 11. I consistently run into this error:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dvisualvm.id=6004111387252 -javaagent:/opt/apps/jetbrains-toolbox/tools/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/192.6817.14/lib/idea_rt.jar=45245:/opt/apps/jetbrains-toolbox/tools/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/192.6817.14/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/peng/git-release/kotlingrad/build/classes/kotlin/main:/home/peng/git-release/kotlingrad/build/resources/main:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jzy3d/jzy3d-api/1.0.2/10445a4cb25bc0b1faa899ade32383abd15bec2/jzy3d-api-1.0.2.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.knowm.xchart/xchart/3.5.4/a0840ad843e2d9a8f5a13f9c96b2b87ff9b8e862/xchart-3.5.4.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.obermuhlner/big-math/2.1.0/9e758e01ce780fd02a4650cb5e0517cbc1cb20ce/big-math-2.1.0.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/scientifik/kmath-core-jvm/0.1.3/3ad6c4aaf4588ec8a3b12842f5e2c231047af7ad/kmath-core-jvm-0.1.3.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/scientifik/kmath-memory-jvm/0.1.3/299bd6661c04333c19acda8b75e95537c6a35fd3/kmath-memory-jvm-0.1.3.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.50/bf65725d4ae2cf00010d84e945fcbc201f590e11/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.50.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core/1.3.0-M1/a89c1a47eb68d6795e2737d84ba1bd81e146ac03/kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.0-M1.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.3.50/50ad05ea1c2595fb31b800e76db464d08d599af3/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.50.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.50/b529d1738c7e98bbfa36a4134039528f2ce78ebf/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.openjfx/javafx-swing/11/ecc43e198238ca46bf3aeaf496e6cafdf63dfeda/javafx-swing-11.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.openjfx/javafx-controls/12.0.1/705ca40565f7cff44fbd6aeae1876de06975bc8c/javafx-controls-12.0.1-linux.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.openjfx/javafx-graphics/12.0.1/16cecc736fb34c555b7bd669a89820b9d0fce3f/javafx-graphics-12.0.1-linux.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.openjfx/javafx-graphics/12.0.1/19ec56a15d7dd9c49112912547425b718485d7db/javafx-graphics-12.0.1.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.openjfx/javafx-base/12.0.1/bacd11da7c8f80868508aaa89b8b22c282dddaf7/javafx-base-12.0.1-linux.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.openjfx/javafx-base/12.0.1/6abae81d00e0c6f4fde02e2666f9c0b989ff47e4/javafx-base-12.0.1.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jzy3d/jzy3d-jdt-core/1.0.2/b8f2111bb5ed951f0afa2aaaf38c71defb4290da/jzy3d-jdt-core-1.0.2.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.gluegen/gluegen-rt-main/2.3.2/6a86a9ce357c085e3052efcf639447f9957b82b8/gluegen-rt-main-2.3.2.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.jogl/jogl-all-main/2.3.2/6a86a9ce357c085e3052efcf639447f9957b82b8/jogl-all-main-2.3.2.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.smurn/jply/0.2.1/9a0432238a166d8b400ea9d45324387a158cdd69/jply-0.2.1.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.sourceforge.jmatio/jmatio/1.0/df72993ea17d34c3bacd983558d2970a866abaf6/jmatio-1.0.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.miglayout/miglayout/3.7.4/9cafd0bc5a567fe6514219e96dc62619471cd4e5/miglayout-3.7.4.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/7999a63bfccbc7c247a9aea10d83d4272bd492c6/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.sf.opencsv/opencsv/2.1/de0cf68e339dc928329fe986a68387531699a01/opencsv-2.1.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.11/4e031bb61df09069aeb2bffb4019e7a5034a4ee0/junit-4.11.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/de.erichseifert.vectorgraphics2d/VectorGraphics2D/0.13/f1ad944da4c6b6a27d244d3a04ce1c67b8b026b6/VectorGraphics2D-0.13.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.50/3d9cd3e1bc7b92e95f43d45be3bfbcf38e36ab87/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.50.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/annotations/13.0/919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9/annotations-13.0.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-io/commons-io/2.3/cd8d6ffc833cc63c30d712a180f4663d8f55799b/commons-io-2.3.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.1/905075e6c80f206bbe6cf1e809d2caa69f420c76/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.gluegen/gluegen-rt/2.3.2/edc35ccfc13d4a4ad02c50d580874c18bf48bbef/gluegen-rt-2.3.2.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.gluegen/gluegen-rt/2.3.2/4c104c7aef98cda5c404eacb96b1a4e04fe0dd68/gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-android-aarch64.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.gluegen/gluegen-rt/2.3.2/2130295b94ef5c19f85fb4ba6107ca193e987858/gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-android-armv6.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.gluegen/gluegen-rt/2.3.2/477a6bc4f9256d8c9935b75d55e2b7b01314440b/gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-linux-amd64.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.gluegen/gluegen-rt/2.3.2/c55cd566d98d4fcd004b9aaa2c502c8c2dcec192/gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-linux-armv6.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.gluegen/gluegen-rt/2.3.2/f6d3587b061d7ae6e68932fc62317e3500d2112d/gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-linux-armv6hf.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.gluegen/gluegen-rt/2.3.2/da68aff010edd35a9ee89b1801dce6e284c7e673/gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-linux-i586.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.gluegen/gluegen-rt/2.3.2/7227ae9e480354909d80f4df92b30bbb965387be/gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-macosx-universal.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.gluegen/gluegen-rt/2.3.2/9a23cd22c59e3f04082e7589e850b79c9e696dc4/gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-solaris-amd64.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.gluegen/gluegen-rt/2.3.2/a5d9ee96c7a365055fba41e30f9a10f42a3c1a3e/gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-solaris-i586.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.gluegen/gluegen-rt/2.3.2/85213c97a5a50d8dd37de4c35ef32cd4b0ac2ef0/gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-windows-amd64.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.gluegen/gluegen-rt/2.3.2/f9b848384a343f39f454e59cead435c2c0cbf542/gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-windows-i586.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.jogl/jogl-all/2.3.2/99e0f64bb8882f054825ae4a8a527a17b544a0b5/jogl-all-2.3.2.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.jogl/jogl-all/2.3.2/166147f43cf7419c4d858cd31f4b5922d6d10c81/jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-android-aarch64.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.jogl/jogl-all/2.3.2/ab2c18b8a1327255cc354c19c720807d262baa75/jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-android-armv6.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.jogl/jogl-all/2.3.2/ffd1c6bd5f6fb088df6cad25e25721eb55ad2228/jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-linux-amd64.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.jogl/jogl-all/2.3.2/6d14f46336be9e2dc5f85d5df17490cee5d09a90/jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-linux-armv6.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.jogl/jogl-all/2.3.2/2c434c560dbd821b0ed569e44d3d441727491dac/jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-linux-armv6hf.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.jogl/jogl-all/2.3.2/59b7a336c0ee54161e33662d2ca8ac9d8f6c476d/jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-linux-i586.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.jogl/jogl-all/2.3.2/2da2215dbe1091c54cb83cf2484f8a54a4d0cf7a/jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-macosx-universal.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.jogl/jogl-all/2.3.2/bde11ff064181af9c307180d8f3f1744b7bdc11d/jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-solaris-amd64.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.jogl/jogl-all/2.3.2/94d1ed501fe53b7f75eab0f712f39802390d0f5b/jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-solaris-i586.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.jogl/jogl-all/2.3.2/becd519b1f741176561d93645abd90971ca0dca0/jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-windows-amd64.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.jogl/jogl-all/2.3.2/5db8db5eca6b4445db6cd14f68938736630ae976/jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-windows-i586.jar:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar edu.umontreal.kotlingrad.samples.Plot3DKt
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.jogamp.common.os.NativeLibrary$3 (file:/home/peng/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jogamp.gluegen/gluegen-rt/2.3.2/edc35ccfc13d4a4ad02c50d580874c18bf48bbef/gluegen-rt-2.3.2.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.findLibrary(java.lang.String)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.jogamp.common.os.NativeLibrary$3
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-lookup.c: 112: check_match: Assertion `version->filename == NULL || ! _dl_name_match_p (version->filename, map)' failed!
```

I have both JDK 8 and JDK 11 installed in Ubuntu 18.04. Both of them are necessary so [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/532054/program-crashes-with-the-error-inconsistency-detected-by-ld-so-dl-lookup-c-11) is not an option

My problem is: how to solve it without uninstalling any of the JDK?